# implement Broadcast Tree on OMNET++

Tags: algorithm, omnet++, distributed-algorithm

I am implementing algorithms concerning the distributed algorithms module and after the spanning tree protocol our teacher has asked us to implement an improved version Strategy Broadcast-Tree Construction consisting on :
i. determine a center c of G;
ii. construct a breadth-first spanning tree BFT(c,G) rooted in c.

but i have problem with the first point to determine the center of network so i can't keep going on and i need help
so if anyone tried and get a solution give me a push

Comment: Hi! This question lacks details to be answered. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); in your case [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on homework may also be relevant.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

- construct a spanning tree, since finding center existing algorithms work on a tree.
- use a modified saturation technique to find centers [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220404603_Distributed_Algorithms_for_Finding_Centers_and_Medians_in_Networks)
- start a BFT from a center.